# remote desktop inside another remote desktop I have problem disconnecting from inner one

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

I'm using a remote desktop inside another machine to connect to another machine with another remote desktop (even a couple of more times of such a chain)

however when i'm inside the second one (or thirdone in chain) and i want to get back to its parent i cant do it.

when i go to top of the screen the title bars of all remote desktops overlay one on each other, even if i hit the clip button on the remote desktop title it does not work all of them goes up.

i tried shortcuts like ctrl-alt-break nothing works i searched for all keyboard shortcuts for remote desktop and nothing help...

can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your Reemote Desktop clients to the new ones from Microsoft.

With those, the titel bar is MOVABLE. This means you can "sort them" until you get to the one you need and then close that one.

This was introduced later than your server version, but an update is available (there are also new features the CLIENT s upports- like multi monitor setups -  but that needs a more modern server than you have).

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

@Jason: Thanks for the suggestion for tsadmin.  I also just found out about the command: "tsdiscon".  Seems to be exactly what we want :)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785968(WS.10).aspx

**... Before edits:**

The way I have solved this in the past is to get out of fullscreen mode in the parent window, which then (usually) allows me access to the toolbar at the top.  Couple this with pinning/unpinning, and it's gotten me through it.

It really is a pain.

Also, if you can somehow get the host key to transfer correctly across chained VMs, you can access the parent VM to alt-tab or get to the taskbar.

You could also (equally painfully) re-open your session that you're trying to break out of in a higher context, which will kick out the original version of the session.  Of course, this won't work if you're bridge networks by using remote sessions...

Comment: The way I have solved this in the past is to get out of fullscreen  mode in the parent window, and (really painfully) put my cursor very, very close to the top of the page.

I just tried that - I didn't succeed i didn't under how the "very close to the top of the screen" is going to help me? thanks

Comment: @Jason: Sorry if that's not helpful.  It's been flaky for me, as well.  What I mean is, sometimes I had to place the cursor at the very top of the parent window.

Comment: Hi
I'm doing tsadmin
and disconnecting myself

Comment: @Jason: Added info about "tsdiscon".  If you like your program better, though, go ahead and answer your own question and accept it.  Won't hurt my feelings at all! :)